# Swipe the menu items of bottom navigation bar

Tags: android, swipe, bottomnavigationview

I am trying to add 4 items in menu of Bottom Navigation View but I cant figure out how to make it swipeable. The screenshot looks like this. I have figured out the increase in size but once I get to know the swiping so that a complete name can be visible or either wrap text can be applied.

[image: bottom Navigation View]

My menu file is;

```
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_1"
        android:title="Triggered Insan" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_2"
        android:title="Carry Minati" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_3"
        android:title="Hadd Bc" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_4"
        android:title="Lakshay Chaudhary" />
   
</menu>
```

Comment: did you find it ? please write answer!!